# Anyway to read and write .png file and link .txt file named the same as .png file?

Tags: c#, image, text, datagridview

Its made in Windows Forms at the most, in a button

```
 public Photo(string filename)
            {
                bitmap = new Bitmap(filename); /*shows the picture.png */
                CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(filename).ToString(); /*shows creationtime of picture*/
                Filelink = filename; /*shows filename opened*/
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filename); /*shows opened file path*/
                /*Description = FileMode.Open.ToString(filename);*/


 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
                {
                    Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*"
                };
    
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    
                    try
                    {
                        Photo photoph = new Photo(ofd.FileName);
                        /*dataGridView1.Rows.Add(photoph.bitmap, photoph.FileName, photoph.Filelink, photoph.CreationDate);*/
                        listing.Add(ofd.FileName, dataGridView1);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Impossible to open file. Choose another one", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the actual problem is. It is easy enough to create a txt file named the same as a png file. But what do you mean by "linking them"? What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to make it in DataGridView, files named the same but i dont know how to implement it in code.
By "linking" I meant that it suppoesed to open files .png and .txt at the same time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `Multiselect` property of OpenFileDialog. In this way you can open multiple file (in your case same file name with different extensions) and show them to users.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog{ Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*"};

DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Read the files
    foreach (var file in ofd.FileNames) 
    {
       // Do your things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I already found solution and made it with Replace:

```
public Photo(string filename)
        {
            string s = "";
            s = filename.Remove(filename.Length-3, 3);
            s += "txt";
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(s, FileMode.Open,
           FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsIn))
            {
                string input;
                while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    input = sr.ReadLine();
                    Description += input;
                }
                bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
                CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(filename).ToString();
                Filelink = filename;
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                Description = File.ReadAllText(s);/*FileMode.Open.ToString(filename);*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm. Can you [edit] your answer to offer more details about your solution? As it stands, this doesn't really offer enough information to help future readers solve a similar problem.